# Solve $\sqrt {x^2-3}=x-3$ in $\mathbb R$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Solve $\sqrt {x^2-3}=x-3$ in $\mathbb R$

My attempt:

$|x^2-3|=(x-3)^2$

So $-(x^2-3)=(x-3)^2$ or $(x^2-3)=(x-3)^2$

If  $-(x^2-3)=(x-3)^2=x^2+9-6x$

So no solutions in $\mathbb R$

And if $(x^2-3)=(x-3)^2$

So $x^2-3=x^2+9-6x$

Now, can I delete $x^2$ with $x^2$ ? Like this

$x^2-x^2-3-9+6x=0$

$6x=12$

$x=2$

But $f(2)$ isn’t equal to $0$?

Comment: $D_f=${$x \in \mathbb R | x \geq \sqrt {3}$} ?

Comment: Sorry but $$\left(\sqrt a\right)^2=a$$ and never $-a$...

Comment: @Did Thank you so much, yeah you are right.

Comment: @gimusi ok, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From

$$\sqrt {x^2-3}=x-3$$

what we need stricktly as condition is that $x^2-3\ge 0$, then we can square both sides

$$\sqrt {x^2-3}=x-3\iff x^2-3=(x-3)^2$$

and for $x\neq 3$, noting that $x=3$ is not a solution, we obtain

$$\iff x^2-3=x^2-6x+9 \iff 6x=12\iff x=2$$

but since $x=2$ doesn't satisfy the equation it is to reject.

This is a legit way to solve, the extra solution come in from squaring both sides but we can exclude it at the end by checking directly on the original equation.

As an alternative we can observe that since LHS is $\ge 0$ also RHS must be then $x-3\ge0 $ is required by the original equation.

Comment: LHS is $x^2-3 \neq (x-3)(x+3)$

Comment: @ops...of course thanks I fix!

Comment: @Dima You are welcome, do not hesitate to ask for any other clarification. Bye

Comment: @gimusi sure, Thank you for your kindness :)

Answer (score 4):

$$\sqrt {x^2-3}=x-3$$

Since, by definition, $\sqrt {x^2-3} \ge 0$, we must have $x-3\ge 0$. That is we must have $x \ge 3$.

If $x \ge 3$, then $x^2-3 \ge 6$. So there will be no complications caused by squaring both sides of the equation.

\begin{align}
   x^2-3 &= x^2-6x + 9 \\
   6x &= 12 \\
   x &= 2
\end{align}

Since we need $x \ge 3$, there is no solution.

Answer (score 2):

What you solved is correct but you must notice that $$\sqrt {x^2-3}\ge 0\Rightarrow x-3\ge 0\Rightarrow x\ge 3$$

And hence I'd you get any solution less than $3$ then you have to reject it.

Comment: $\sqrt {2^2-3}=\sqrt {4-3}=\sqrt {1}=1$

Comment: @MichaelMcGovern That is the problem first you must limit the domain of x before starting to solve. $$\sqrt {x^2-3}=x-3\ge 0$$

Comment: $\sqrt{x^2-3}\ge0\nRightarrow{x}-3\ge0$
$\sqrt{x^2-3}=x-3\Rightarrow{x}-3\ge0$

Answer (score 2):

When you solve an equation by squaring both sides, it's possible that extraneous solutions are introduced.  An extraneous solution is a value that you get at the end (like $x=2$ here) that doesn't actually solve the original equation.  This is exactly what happened here.  Since $x=2$ is the only value you got, and since it doesn't solve the original equation, that means the equation has no real solutions.

This can also be verified by graphing $y = \sqrt{x^2-3}$ and $y = x-3$ on the same axes and noticing that they never intersect.

Note also that $\left(\sqrt{x^2-3}\right)^2$ is just $x^2 - 3$, not $|x^2-3|$.  So considering $-(x^2 - 3) = (x-3)^2$ is technically incorrect, but you got lucky here in that it also has no real solutions.  Still, you should remove it completely from your work.

Comment: $2$ is not an extraneous solution.

Comment: @MichaelMcGovern, yes, it most certainly is.  Plug it into the original equation and you  get $1 = -1$.

Comment: You're right. One of the answer provided an incorrect justification for $2$ being an extraneous solution.

Comment: @MichaelMcGovern, I see no errors in  the other answers, only a sloppy shortcut in one of them.  If you're talking about the other answer you commented on, that one is perfectly fine.  Since $\sqrt{x^2 - 3} \ge 0$ by definition, and since $\sqrt{x^2 - 3} = x-3$, then $x-3 \ge 0$ as well, and so any value of $x$ that's less than $3$ must be rejected.

Comment: The answer didn't say that though.

Comment: @MichaelMcGovern, that doesn't make it incorrect.  It's just missing some details.

Comment: Technically the answer did say that, it just wasn't explicit about the first implication.  I do think that being very clear about stuff like that is important for students at the OP's level, which I'm assuming is precalc/college algebra, based on the question.

Answer (score 1):

I was taught to always find the domain of possible solutions first. We have 
\begin{cases}
x-3 \ge 0, \\
x^2-3 \ge0 
\end{cases} or \begin{cases}
x \ge 3, \\
-\sqrt{3} \le x \le \sqrt{3}
\end{cases}
which has no solutions

Comment: @Dima: You are always welcome. Btw, my best friend's name is Dima.

Comment: oh nice, give her my great :)